# Finding multiple matches with multiline regex perl

Tags: perl

This code:

```
#!/bin/perl

BEGIN { $/ = undef; };
open (FILE,"file.txt") ||  die "Cannot open $FILE:$!";

while (<FILE>) {
    my @matches;

    if  ( m#SelectEditPolicy\.do\?policyID=[0-9]{1,4}.*?">(.*?)</a>#sg) {
        push (@matches,$1);
    }

    foreach $rec (@matches) {
        print "$rec\n";
    }
}
```

against this file:

```
>cat file.txt
SelectEditPolicy.do?policyID=2958')">
Test123  OLD</a>
SelectEditPolicy.do?policyID=6643')">
Test123 </a>
```

Executing file.pl returns only the first match. I've read as many post as I can w/o any success?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You are doing quite a few things wrong. The first one that sticks out is `BEGIN { $/ = undef; };` If you want to slurp a file, set `$/ = undef` in the smallest applicable scope. In addition, once you have decided to slurp a file, there is no reason to use a `while` loop pretending to read it line-by-line.

Second, you seem to have done some pre-processing on an HTML file to reduce it to a form where you can apply regexes. Your life would have been easier using something like [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser%3a%3aSimple).

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $content = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my @matches = ($content =~ m{
        SelectEditPolicy\.do\?
        policyID=[0-9]{1,4}[^>]*?">
        ([^<]*?)
        </a>
}xsg );

print "$_\n" for @matches;

__DATA__
SelectEditPolicy.do?policyID=2958')">
Test123  OLD</a>
SelectEditPolicy.do?policyID=6643')">
Test123 </a>
```

Output:

```
Test123  OLD

Test123
```

Using [HTML::TokeParser::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/HTML%3a%3aTokeParser%3a%3aSimple) with the original HTML, I might have done something like this (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TokeParser::Simple;

my $parser = HTML::TokeParser::Simple->new(url => 'http://example.com/');

my @policies;

while (my $tag = $parser->get_tag('a')) {
    my $href = $tag->get_attr('href');
    next unless defined $href;
    next unless $href =~ /SelectEditPolicy\.do\?policyID=([0-9]{1,4})/;
    push @policies, { $1 => $parser->get_text('/a') };
}
```

Comment: Awesome. This is great and really help a newer perl scripter. Can you explain what "__DATA__" does?

Comment: See "Special Literals" in http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html : `DATA` is a special filehandle that allows you to read text included in the `__DATA__` section. In this case, it allowed me to write a self-contained example script that did not depend on external files.